# Why My User control not auto instance in InitializeComponent() of the Form.designer.cs?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I create a custom Textbox extend the original Textbox

```
 internal sealed class CustomTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private Label _label;

        internal CustomTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _label.Visible = true;
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            _label = new Label();
        }

      ``    ``      
}
```

But after I drag it into my Form. It always can't auto generate **new instance** in InitializeComponent() in The **Form.designer.cs**

```
   /// <summary>
   /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
   /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
   /// </summary>
   private void InitializeComponent()
            {
               // I always need to add it manually, it can't audo generate , even I manually add it and I change any other control , it will dissapeared
                this.customTextbox = new CustomTextBox(); 


                 this.SuspendLayout();

                 // this can normal generate, and will not dissapeared
                 this.Controls.Add(this.customTextbox);
                    ``           ``
                 this.ResumeLayout(false);
                 this.PerformLayout();
            }

private CustomTextBox customTextbox;
```

I can't understand why. Why the `this.customTextbox = new CustomTextBox()` can't auto generate? if I drag into this Form any other control, it will just **dissapeared again**.

Thank you.

Comment: Why you marked that constructor as **internal**?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, It's only use in same project, It's for safe.

Comment: Class itself is internal...I'm not sure designer will generate code for a non-public constructor.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, You right, It's my mistake. All because the constructor is internal. Now I change it Public , All fine. Please answer it , I use it to best answer, That will help other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Designer cannot handle non-public members, it'll let you use your control in design surface because it parses code (constructor visibility and parameters are ignored) but it won't generate any code for that.

Your class is  `internal` class then your constructor can safely be `public`.

.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing the control is not enough. Try `Controls.Add(yourCustomTextbox);`.

And your custom textbox has nothing in design. You have not added the label to the controls of custom textbox as well.

Comment: Yes, it has. I just not include it, It's correct generate.

Comment: The label just used for another reason. It dissapeared because the label?

Comment: I just saw only a label in the initializecomponent method. If it has other controls aded, of course it is not because of the label.

Comment: @qakmak By the way, are the customTextBox and form in the same project?

Comment: @qakmak If not change the modifier of the customTextbox to `public`.

Comment: Yes, In the same project. For safe.